# Is there a way to run a command on multiple Windows servers in parallel

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

Every now and then, I need to run a command on multiple Windows servers (synchronize files from a source code repository containing script files [and other random stuff]). The execution time of this command is dominated by network latency.

Currently, I use PowerShell's Invoke-Command cmdlet, but it runs the command sequentially on each host. Since this script takes its sweet time to run (sometimes a couple of minutes per server), I would like to speed things up by running the command in parallel on all servers at once.

Invoke-Command, as far as I could figure out, cannot do this. SysInternals' psexec cannot do this either.

I am vaguely aware that PowerShell has a parallel looping facility that can execute several iterations of the loop simultaneously on several threads. But documentation states that this is only available in a PowerShell workflow, which I am not familiar with, and it kind of sounds like this is massive overkill.

In a Unix-y shell, I could run each invocation of psexec in the background. But to my knowledge, PowerShell does not support this. Or I could use tool like GNU parallel or ts.

Is there a (simple) way to do this on a Windows 7 machine?

If all else fails, I could write a Perl-Script or something, but why reinvent the wheel? Surely I am not the first person to run into this problem.

Comment: GNU Parallel defaults to using SSH, so unless you want it to run another tool to connect with, then you need to run a ssh-service on the servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Powershell Jobs to run multiple Invoke-Commands in parallel. How this works exactly has already been explained at Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781666/run-n-parallel-jobs-in-powershell

I'm copying it here for your reference, slightly adapted to your use case:

> The Start-Job cmdlet allows you to run code in the background.

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $running = @(Get-Job | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' })
    if ($running.Count -le 8) {
        Start-Job {
             $list = Invoke-Command -FilePath .\file.ps1 -ComputerName <hostname>
             ...
        }
    } else {
         $running | Wait-Job
    }
    Get-Job | Receive-Job
}
```